# Need clear and simple clarification on the difference between accuracy and precision

Tags: statistics, terminology

Could someone suggest a better explanation of the difference between "accuracy and precision concept" other than this very common approach which is not clear to me.

**EDIT**

For example:
Why is picture in top rights corner is "precise"? Is it because the dots are within the outer circle? Or is it because the dots are clustered together? What about the distance between the clustered dots center and the radius of the inner circle, this could be huge, would it still be precise?

Thank you.

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: What about this explanation confuses you? I can’t imagine there is another way to explain the difference besides just trying to describe this picture.

Comment: It depends on how you define "accurate":  if it is saying you are pointing in the right direction in general, but there is unbiased error - possibly substantial - then you get the top-left and bottom-left outcomes described as accurate;  if it is saying each individual case must be close then you restrict yourself to the top-left and you need a different word for the bottom-left.  Similarly for "precise" and the top-right   outcome

Comment: According to the pictures , "precise" means "small standard deviation" and "accurate" means "close to the actual mean". But I do not think that the terminology is lucky in this case.

Comment: @Snacc, In response to your question, I have updated the question.

Comment: Peter & Henry thanks for the clarification.

Comment: In [this answer (and the comments underneath it)](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/23238/372), I characterise your given diagram as a statistics/business/science perspective of accuracy-versus-precision, and talk about how the concept/distinction seems to have an orthogonal meaning in numerical analysis. Hopefully it's not too rambly.

Comment: @ryang, Thanks for you help

Comment: I would say we have high precision in all the figures: we can see exactly where each shot landed. If the shots made ugly big ragged holes instead of nice little round holes, the holes would locate the shots with much less precision. I think this figure says more about the difficulty of making analogies than it does about precision and accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

A numerical estimate is accurate if it's close to the true value. It's precise if you know it to many decimal places.

A clumsy but well conceived laboratory experiment could produce an accurate measurement that wasn't precise.

A well executed but faultily designed experiment could find lots of correct decimal places for a result nowhere near what you thought you were measuring.